# Bitly INVALID_URI - '500'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-shortener

I am using the Bitly gem (https://github.com/philnash/bitly) for Bitly API Version 3

I get an error while shortening the URL when the application is deployed to Heroku. Locally the shortening works fine.

```
def get_short_url(url)
    Bitly.use_api_version_3
    bitly = Bitly.new(Settings.bitly.login, Settings.bitly.api_key)
    result = bitly.shorten(url) ----------------- Line 3
    result.short_url
end
```

Line 3 in the code above gives INVALID_URI - '500' error.

The URL I am trying to shorten is

```
"https://rs-4615.xyz.com/users/profile_view/20492083"
```

It shortens fine when I use bitly.com.

I am unable to figure out the issue. Can anyone help?

Shardul.

Comment: are you encoding the url before passing it into **#shorten**? The docs seem to say that this means there's an issue with the link. maybe double encoding.

Comment: if the trouble only seems to be up on heroku, then what are the differences between the two environments? are you using postgres as your local dev database? could heroku's postgres db be screwing with your string?

Comment: Hi jstim,

Sorry for the delay in responding. I am using postgres as my local dev database. Is it possible that the Heroku DB has a different encoding than my local dev db and that is causing an issue?

Comment: I'll have to look into that. My concern was that maybe you were using sqlite locally and heroku's postgres. I'll try to think about it this evening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Answering and accepting just in case someone else comes across the same issue.***

The problem was that the URL generated in my code, did not PREPEND the 'https' protocol to the URL and so the failure.

So, what was generated was

```
rs-4615.xyz.com/users/profile_view/20492083
```

INSTEAD OF

`https://rs-4615.xyz.com/users/profile_view/20492083` -- This is the correct one.

@jstim, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Another thing Bit.ly doesn't like is if the hostname in the URL is 'localhost'. I was trying this out in my development environment, and changing the hostname to something else fixed my problem.

Comment: Bit.ly does allow 'lvh.me' which is nice b/c that will redirect to localhost.